# Mysql python - randomly (every other attempt) gets access denied

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I can't figure this out and i am not sure how to code for it.

```
def get_connection():
    cnx = MySQLdb.connect(**DB_CONFIG)
    print("Connected")
    cnx.close()
    print("Closed")


12:08 $ python test_mysql.py  && python test_mysql.py 
Connected
Closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_mysql.py", line 4, in <module>
    get_connection()
  File "XX"/mysql/tbred_mysql.py", line 7, in get_connection
    cnx = MySQLdb.connect(**DB_CONFIG)
  File "XX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "XX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'XXXX'@'10.0.8.5' (using password: YES)")
```

I ran them right after each other because it was easier to demonstrate but you can wait 10 or 15 seconds and it will still happen. I works and then it doesn't.

When it fails like this nothing is written to the mysql error log. If i change the user to something that doesn't exist to force this error a record is written to the mysql error log.

EDIT:
I can reproduce problem without python. If i try and remote connect via the mysql command line client in linux i get the same results. Also i have discovered its not random its every other connection regardless of time between attempts. 1st works, 2nd error, 3rd works, 4th errors again it doesn't matter the time between them. Also with these failures they are not recorded to the mysql error log like a normal access denied message is.

Losing my mind!

Comment: Just wanted to add that before using mysql-python i tried the mysql connector and had they exact same results which is why i switched thinking something was up with the connector. Not the case.

Comment: my workaround is to just connect again on error unless its two errors in row then exit. Works perfectly and this is ugly and hacky and doesn't make sense. Very frustrated

Comment: OK i solved it i had to set the host the mysql IP and not hostname. I don't know why this would cause this specific and weird error but it did. I am going to leave open and anyone that can explain to my why it fixed can have the answer. an entire day wasted.

Comment: I suggest setting the `skip_name_resolve` option in my.cnf on the server. This will remove the need for mysqld to verify the client's hostname using DNS. If you have intermittently flaky DNS, that could fix it. As well as speeding up opening connections.

Comment: Add that as an answer. Fixes the issue and speeds up connections much better than my "i did this and it worked but i am not 100% sure why".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating this from my comment above.

Setting option `skip_name_resolve` fixes your issue.

By default, MySQL Server tries to do a reverse DNS lookup of the client IP address to make sure your user is logging in from an authorized hostname. This is a problem if your local DNS server is slow or intermittently flaky. It can slow down or even cause errors for MySQL connections, and it's not clear why.

Using `skip_name_resolve` tells the server to skip this validation. This should eliminate errors and slow performance due to DNS.

One implication of this is that you cannot use hostnames in `GRANT` statements. You must identify users' authorized client hosts by IP addresses or wildcards like `%`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html says:

> To disable DNS host name lookups, start the server with the --skip-name-resolve option. In this case, the server uses only IP addresses and not host names to match connecting hosts to rows in the MySQL grant tables. Only accounts specified in those tables using IP addresses can be used. (Be sure that an account exists that specifies an IP address or you may not be able to connect.)

Wildcards work too. You can `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'192.168.%'` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Had to use the ip of the server instead of the hostname. Problem was caused by dns resolution issues on the server. The way that it failed still boggles my mind.